# When navigate to lazy loaded module directly user service not available

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

In my angular application, I have few lazily loaded modules with app module when I go through homepage to lazily loaded modules it works fine. but if I enter lazily loaded module URL in web browser data in user service shows undefined. How can I fix this?

[image]

User Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

export class UserService {
  private isUserLoggedIn;
  private sideNavstatus;
  private subsideNavstatus;
  public username;
  public userDetails;
  public jobCard;
  public sideNav;
  public subsideNav;
  public sidestat;
  public subsidestat;

  constructor() {
    this.isUserLoggedIn = false;
  }

  setUserLoggedInStatus(status) {
    this.isUserLoggedIn = status;
    this.username = 'User_1';

    this.userDetails = {
      name: {
        fristName: "Carolyn",
        middleName: "Ann",
        lastName: "Stewart",
      },
      profileImages: 'assets/images/dummy_back_end/user_1.png',
    };

    this.sideNav = true;
    this.subsideNav = true;
    this.sideNavstatus = this.sideNav;
    this.subsideNavstatus = this.subsideNav;
    this.jobCard = {
      jobCardTitle: {
        title: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text",
        from: "Theresa Jenkins",
      }
    }
  }

  getUserLoggedIn() {
    return this.isUserLoggedIn;
  }
}
```

App Module

```
@NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        DashboardComponent,
        UserComponent,
        NotfoundComponent,
        LoginComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        SharableModule,
        // UserModule
        // Chart
      ],
      // providers:[UserService,AuthguardGuard],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],

    })
    export class AppModule { }
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

App Routing

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: ' ', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: './customer/customer.module#CustomerModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard', canActivate: [AuthguardGuard], component:
    DashboardComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'requests', loadChildren: './job-card/job- 
       card.module#JobCardModule'},
       { path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Customer Module

```
 @NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CustomerRoutingModule,
    SharableModule,
    FormsModule,
    QuillModule,
    // UserModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    CustomerlistComponent
  ],

  export class CustomerModule { }
```

Comment: add If condition in html where your are going to print title. eg. <div *ngIf="title">{{title}}</div> this will remove your html undefined error.

Comment: Do you have your jobCardTitle interface imported?

Comment: @AbhishekJaiswal do I need to import jobCard interface to feature module?

Comment: @AbhishekJaiswal I think this problem beacuse user service singleton class not avilable in lazyloaded module